# nested mysql case when

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
 SELECT    ( CASE 
                        WHEN 1944.0000 >= country_from_price 
                            AND 1944.0000 <= country_to_price
                        THEN ((1944.0000 + ((1944.0000 * country_percentage)/100)))
                            ELSE 1944.0000
                        END 
                        )   
                       FROM `country_markup` 
                       WHERE estatus = '1' 
                       AND country_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]138[[:>:]]'
```

Above query return value increased by percent but if condition is not full fill than it return  NULL. What i want is if query return NULL value than it should return 1944.0000 
and For this i have tried below code but did not get any success

```
SELECT  IF( (SELECT (CASE 
                        WHEN 1944.0000 >= country_from_price 
                            AND 1944.0000 <= country_to_price
                        THEN ((1944.0000 + ((1944.0000 * country_percentage)/100)))
                            ELSE 1944.0000
                        END 
                        )   as f1
                       FROM `country_markup` 
                       WHERE estatus = '1' 
                       AND country_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]223[[:>:]]') IS NOT NULL, f1  ,1944.0000) as final_price
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: Please check this [link] sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c49df0/1

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work with `COALESCE` (assuming your original query can only return a single record):

```
SELECT COALESCE((
  SELECT    
      CASE WHEN 1944.0000 >= country_from_price AND 1944.0000 <= country_to_price
          THEN ((1944.0000 + ((1944.0000 * country_percentage)/100)))
               ELSE 1944.0000
          END         
  FROM `country_markup` 
  WHERE estatus = '1' 
      AND country_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]138[[:>:]]'), 1944.0000) final_price
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b105/2)

You can add `LIMIT 1` to your subquery to make sure it only returns a single record as well if needed.

---

Here's an alternative using the `MAX` aggregate with `COALESCE`:

```
  SELECT    
      COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN 1944.0000 >= country_from_price AND 1944.0000 <= country_to_price
          THEN ((1944.0000 + ((1944.0000 * country_percentage)/100)))
               ELSE 1944.0000
          END ),1944.0000)    final_price   
  FROM `country_markup` 
  WHERE estatus = '1' 
      AND country_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]138[[:>:]]'
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c264/7)

Comment: thank a lot but it is not working in mysql function
[link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c49df0/1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test that the `country_percentage` is not null in your expression:

```
SELECT    (CASE WHEN 1944.0000 between country_from_price AND country_to_price and
                     country_percentage is not null
                THEN ((1944.0000 + ((1944.0000 * country_percentage)/100)))
                ELSE 1944.0000
            END)   
FROM `country_markup` 
WHERE estatus = '1' AND country_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]138[[:>:]]';
```

I also changed the comparison logic to use `between`.

Comment: Thanks but when condition is not full fill it return blank array but i do not want that.

Comment: @NayDev . . . You need to post sample data and expected results.  I, for one, don't understand what you are asking for.  Neither this query nor your original returns an array, blank or otherwise.

Comment: Please check it [link] sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c49df0/1. Here I have added mysql table structure and data as well. Also have the mysql fuction i have created.

Comment: @NayDev . . . What is the problem?  Your stored procedure doesn't compile because it needs to be on the left panel of sql fiddle.  The above code returns no rows because the country does not match.

Comment: [link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0a2ee/3 I have inserted table and query. This query would never return null value. If there is not value it will return the price i have use to compare i.e. 1944.00.Now i would like to create mysql function where i pass the country_id(223) and price(1944.0000) than it should return the same result as this query giving while i run it independently.